# creating interface for pacman and trying to draw the ghosts. The code is running but the ghost isnt appearing

Tags: c#, forms, pacman

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap ghost32 = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"..\\..\\ghost32.PNG", true);

        TextureBrush texture = new TextureBrush(ghost32);
        texture.WrapMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.Tile;
        Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        formGraphics.FillEllipse(texture,
            new RectangleF(90.0F, 110.0F, 100, 100));
        formGraphics.Dispose();

    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error opening the bitmap." +
            "Please check the path.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the ghost just gets drawn once when the button is clicked. This doesn't necessarily mean the drawn ghost will be displayed on the screen, or that it will stay there for long. Try making your form overload the `OnPaint` method, then draw the ghost there.

Comment: Hi @MariusUt ; I'm not familiar with this method, where exactly would I implement this? I'm relatively new to c#.

Comment: It's a bit complicated, too complicated to explain here. If you search google and stuff, you'd find some good tutorials. I'm sure you'll figure it out ;) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
private Image[] ghost = new Image[1];
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
internal void Paint_Ghost(Graphics g)
{
g.DrawImage(ghostImage[currentPoistion], xPosition, yPosition, 50, 50);
}
public void DrawGhost_LoadRight()
{  
ghostImage[0] = Image.FromFile("ghost.png");
}
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Paint_Ghost(g);
}
```

Comment: On the right track here. You'll have to use the Paint event for whatever control you wish to paint to. e.Graphics is the way to go. For example, minimizing or maximizing a screen will repaint the entire control, making your previous drawings disappear.